# Authorize popup Philips Android TV not showing

Tags: adb, android-tv

I'm trying to connect my Philips Android TV to ADB. I'm getting that the device isn't authorized. If I do a 'ADB connect ' then it tells me I'm already connected. It's true that it's not authorized since I don't get the popup on my TV to authorize it.

I searched around on the internet and found a few things. Revoking all authorizations, killing the adb service and restarting it, removing the adb keys in the .android map and setting the TV on a TV channel (cause apparently the popup doesn't show in the Android menu).

Are there other things I can try to resolve this problem?

Comment: [DufloDocus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14672093/duflodocus) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921102/12695027) saying "It worked with me (also Philips Android TV) https://github.com/eslavnov/android-tv-remote/issues/1#issuecomment-586389823"

Comment: Thanks, but now I have an nvidia shield, which is much better 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Finally it worked after I unplugged the TV during 1 minute and plugged it back.